# IMAP email not received but it is in the logs

Tags: email, email-server, imap, dovecot

Our server has apparently lost some email. The company's client says that 2 emails were supposed to have been received and I looked through `/var/log/mail.log*` files by using zgrep and the two emails turned up. However, when I searched through the mailbox, only one of the emails was there. The client has assured me that he didn't accidentally delete the 2nd email, but I have no idea where it could have gone.

Are there any other log files that I can check or has the client simply forgotten that he deleted the email ([PEBKAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pebkac#Acronyms_and_other_names_for_a_user_error))

Comment: I suspect this is a user issue. I see this often in our MSP business.  The only recourse we have is to look for a login even and show that email was downloaded after delivery.  Depending on backup and email trash emptying, you may be able to find a copy.

Comment: by login you mean the IMAP check sent by their email client? is that in the mail.log files or mail.info or somewhere else? It is quite annoying to have to explain things like this :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If log says that both emails were successfully delivered to the mailbox, then most probably client has deleted the mail(might be unintentionally) or has ended up as spam in the client's email client's spam filter.